# Rotating Images w/jQuery... But Resizing Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I have an image that needs to be rotated. This image is oriented either landscape or portrait.

I have an HTML5 form to accept the degrees of rotation with a step 90 each click. When this value changes, the image should rotate and resize. It should always be 770px wide, but can be as tall as it needs to be.

I've written the following event handler, but it doesn't work the way I'd expect.

Use Case: When the image is portrait, it's initial values are 770x1027 (w x h). When rotating it 90 degrees, I would expect the below function to rotate the image, set the width = 1027 and height = 770. But what I'm seeing is that both width and height are being set to 770. What am I not seeing?

```
$("#degrees").change(function(){
    var element$ = $("#photo-submission"),
        w = element$.width(), 
        h = element$.height(),
        deg = $(this).val();


    element$.removeAttr("style").attr({
        "style": "-webkit-transform:rotate("+ deg +"deg); width: "+ h +"px; height: "+ w + "px;"
    })
});
```

Comment: yes if initially w = 770, h = 1027... when I rotate 90 degrees, I need to resize the image so that it's still no wider than 770, but  because it's now on it's side, the image height is our visual width. Confusing? I know how you feel.

Comment: so you just want to scale if `degrees % 180 == 90`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have switched your width and height.

```
element$.removeAttr("style").attr({
    "style": "-webkit-transform:rotate("+ deg +"deg); width: "+ w +"px; height: "+ h + "px;"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying it with the jQuery method actually made for changing CSS properties, that way it would be easier to keep track of your variables and place them in the right places :

```
$("#degrees").change(function(){
    var el  = $("#photo-submission"),
        w   = el.width(), 
        h   = el.height(),
        deg = this.value;

    el.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' +deg+ 'deg)',
        width  : w,
        height : h
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XhRW/)

The real advantage of this is that you don't have to set the width and height to what it already is, which is basically what you're doing, so this is enough

```
$("#degrees").change(function(){
    $("#photo-submission").css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + this.value + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your JSFiddle, but it shows a square image. That would be pretty straight forward. I'm trying to work with a rectangular image, ensuring that the top left of the image is always in the upper left of it's container and never wider than 770.

Comment: I don't get it at all, you're getting the height and width of an element, and setting the height and width to the exact same values on the exact same element, what does that change ?

Comment: Oh, now I get it, and I believe it's a lot more complicated than this if you're trying to keep the aspect and location of the image on rotation. You should probably look into transform origin and the transform matrix that rotate() is a shortcut for.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Sorry I didn't explain it well. Thanks for the tips, I'm off to look into that now.